# Vectorized Method to create and write to csv an aribrary number of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So currently, I have DataFrames that look like this:

```
          id  temp1  temp2
9       10.0   True  False
10      10.0   True  False
11      10.0  False   True
12      10.0  False   True
17      15.0   True  False
18      15.0   True  False
19      15.0   True  False
20      15.0   True  False
21      15.0  False  False
33      27.0   True  False
34      27.0   True  False
35      27.0  False   True
36      27.0  False  False
40      31.0   True  False
41      31.0  False   True 
           .
           .
           .
```

and I sort through the table with these commands:

```
u = coinc.groupby('id')
m = u.temp1.any() & u.temp2.any()
res = df.loc[coinc.id.isin(m[m].index), ['id']]
```

which check if in any group of the same id, if there is a true in both the temp1 column, and the temp2 column. If there is, it goes in the new "res" DataFrame

Now, I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
         id  temp1_0  temp2_0  temp1_1  temp2_1
9      10.0    False    False     True    False
10     10.0    False    False     True    False
11     10.0    False     True    False    False
12     10.0    False     True    False    False
17     15.0     True    False    False    False
18     15.0     True    False    False    False
19     15.0    False    False     True    False
20     15.0    False    False     True    False
21     15.0    False    False    False    False
33     27.0    False    False     True    False
34     27.0    False    False     True    False
35     27.0    False     True    False    False
36     27.0    False    False    False    False
40     31.0    False    False     True    False
41     31.0    False     True    False    False
```

except, in reality, I will have an arbitrary number of temp columns, but always in groups of two like above.

I was wondering if there was a vectorized way of doing that same opperation above, but for each group of two temp columns (i.e. for the example above it would make two separate dataframes) and then output them to csv according to their name (..._0.csv, ..._1.csv, etc)

Comment: `m = u[list_of_temp_cols].any().all()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang no, this doesn't address my problem